# How to make an UISearchBar taller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

My question is how to resize the height of an UISearchBar to more than 44px. I mean, I need to set a bigger font but the textField is smaller than this font.
I already know how to increase the font:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:28]];
```

But not how to increase the UISearchBar height.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem:

I have changed the UISearchBar size by changing its background image.
This is the code used:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fondoSearchBar.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The image height is 50 so now the UISearchBar height is the same.